# Why did the latest update to VS 2015 uninstall Git?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I just updated VS2015 (Dec. 2015), it installed everything OK but as it finished, I saw a message flash up saying it was uninstalling Git.  There had been an option to updated the MS Git provider, but I had no intention of it uninstalling Git.

Now it has finished, I can see that is has indeed uninstalled it, I can't access Git from Webstorm now.  The directory no longer exists.  I can no longer access Git from Powershell, too.  Github desktop app works, but that uses it's own version of Git.

Obviously, I'm tempted to just re-install it, but what was MS thinking?  Am I missing something about the update process that gave me a better option/alternative to Git that I should re-point Webstorm to?

Webstorm is looking for Git here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe

Visual Studio is using MS Git Provider (I believe it was using normal Git before).

I'm not sure what to do and don't want to break my system further by trying to fix it, any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: If I remember correctly - Git is an optional plugin in Update1 - unchecked during installation even when you have installed it before. Why? It's third-party and probably: https://www.humankode.com/security/how-a-bug-in-visual-studio-2015-exposed-my-source-code-on-github-and-cost-me-6500-in-a-few-hours

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I remember selecting the 'update' option for the Git Plugin (but I still wouldn't expect it to uninstall a totally separate program!).  That link is scary stuff!  Highly organised digital criminals...  I accidentally exposed my Azure keys to Github and got an email from their staff with some helpful links to change them ASAP.  Phew! :)

Answer (score 0):

For now, I'm just using the GitHub version, as I suspect that was MS's intention.  I pointed Webstorm to this folder\file combo (the GitHub portable version).

```
C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_[GUID]\cmd\Git.exe
```

I've also added it to the PATH along with the 'bin' folder, so I could access it from Powershell:

```
C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_[GUID]\bin
C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_[GUID]\cmd
```

Strangely, I'm not seeing any Git options in the VS 2015 context menus for files... I guess they broke everything!  If you have any thoughts on that, I'd be pleased to hear them.